# AS3 Help For Commas

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs6

I have this code and I want commas in my numbers.
The jackpot is €169.85 but it is displayed as `16985 00` in the game. How to fix that?

```
public function jackpotstring():String {
    var myPattern:RegExp = /./; 
    var jp:Number = jackpot * denom;
    var s:String = jp.toFixed(2)+"";
    return s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-_:]+/g, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ou could try something like;

```
var jp:Number = jackpot * denom;
jp = Math.round(jp * 100)/100; // value should be something like 1698500
jp = jp / 10000; // value should be something like 169.85 now
var s:String = String(jp);
return s;
```

Comment: sorry, think I misunderstood your question... what do you want your final output to look like exactly? In your question it says €169.85 ... I don't see any commas?

Comment: The jackpot is €169.85 but it is displayed as 16985 00 i want to output 169.85

Comment: i want the commas (,)

Comment: still confused... you keep saying you want commas,but in the comment above, you said you want it to output 169.85 ... which has no commas... can you specify exactly how you want it, including all commas in correct places. Not sure if you expect me to just know where the commas go, but I live in a part of the world where we don't use commas in currencies...

Comment: SORRY NOW I SEE THA CHANGE :/ THANKYOU VERY MUCH IS WORKING NOW AND SORRY AGAIN :)